# TypeScript - Type Transformation: { key: Kn, value: Vn }[] -> { [key: Kn]: Vn }

Tags: typescript

#### I want to write a function that takes in tuples of the following type/structure:

```
type Input = [
  { key: K1, value: V1 },
  { key: K2, value: V2 },
  { key: K3, value: V3 },
  // ...
  { key: KN, value: VN }
]
```

#### And outputs the following type:

```
type Output = {
  [key: K1]: V1,
  [key: K2]: V2,
  [key: K3]: V3,
  // ...
  [key: KN]: VN
}
```

#### Like this:

```
function fromArray(xs: Input): Output {
  const obj = {} as Output
  for (const x of xs) {
    obj[x.key] = x.value
  }
  return obj
}
```

#### And I want the input and output types to be inferred at compile time given something like:

```
const geometry = fromArray([
  { key: 'circle',    value: { color: 'blue', radius: 3 } },
  { key: 'rectangle', value: { color: 'red', width: 3, height: 2 } },
  { key: 'line',      value: { length: 5 } }
])

// Now, I essentially want autocomplete on the following:
geometry.circle.color  // type = string
geometry.line.length   // type = number
```

### Is this possible with the current version of TypeScript?

I don't mind the type signature of fromArray looking messy.

As far as I'm concerned, it doesn't matter what happens to the output type signature when there are duplicate keys, as I would throw an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I'd write it like this... given `KV`, the generic key/value object type passed in as an element of the `xs` argument to `fromArray()` (or the union of such types), the type `KeyValToObj<T>` corresponding to the output object type is:

```
type KeyValToObj<KV extends { key: PropertyKey, value: any }> =
  { [K in KV['key']]: Extract<KV, { key: K }>['value'] };
```

You can see that if `KV` is a union like `{key: "a", value: string} | {key: "b", value: number}` then, `KeyValToObj<KV>` will have a key `K` for every `key` property in `KV`, and the value will be the corresponding `value` property from the member of `KV` with `key` of type `K`: `{a: string; b: number}`.

Then I'd give `fromArray()` the following signature:

```
function fromArray<XS extends Array<{ key: K, value: any }>, K extends PropertyKey>(
  xs: XS | []): KeyValToObj<XS[number]> {
  const obj = {} as any;
  for (const x of xs) {
    obj[x.key] = x.value
  }
  return obj
}
```

With an `xs` input of type `XS`, we output `KeyValToObj<XS[number]>`, the object type corresponding to the union of element types of `XS`.  We need a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) to `any` to make the implementation not complain; the compiler won't be able to verify that we are actually returning the right output type here, so I didn't bother trying.

There are a few wrinkles to that signature to get type inference working the way I want:  The `K` type seems superfluous (why not replace it with `PropertyKey`?) but is a hint to get the compiler to infer [string literal types](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#string-literal-types) for the `key` properties.  And the `| []` seems superfluous (why explicitly allow an empty tuple when that's one of the things `XS` could be?) but is a hint to the compiler to infer a [tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#tuple) for `XS` instead of an unordered array... which itself seems weird (why do we care about the order of `XS` when we are only using `XS[number]`, the element type?) but is a hint to prevent the compiler from [normalizing the element types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-7.html#improved-type-inference-for-object-literals) to contain all the properties.  If you relax any of those constraints you'll get strange inference behavior.

---

Okay, let's try it:

```
const geometry = fromArray([
  { key: 'circle', value: { color: 'blue', radius: 3 } },
  { key: 'rectangle', value: { color: 'red', width: 3, height: 2 } },
  { key: 'line', value: { length: 5 } }
])

geometry.circle
// circle: { color: string; radius: number; } 
geometry.circle.radius; 

geometry.line
// line: { length: number; }
geometry.line.length;

geometry.rectangle
// rectangle: { color: string; width: number; height: number; }
geometry.rectangle.width;
```

Looks good. You get all the autocomplete you wanted.  For what it's worth, if you use a duplicate key, the output type has a union of the corresponding value types at that key.

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBA0hIDUCGAbAKgewPICMBWAPDAlBAB7AQB2AJgM5QDeUA1vAFxQAKAThpD1BwQAGigA3VAFcInJFRBQAvgD4oAXgCwAKChMoAbRhQAllVgIDAcjYgrAXXucAohR5IAxsCIIxzW5zGqtaSKDIOygDcOjoAZlJUXiYY5rF8ALYAgjzuIAQAGgDKpBTU9FDZuQT+HLBioTJyCsoqYsbklLQMvPwQgiDCKgAUOnpkdJxFUAA+hvYAlIHwyOjY+AWFBlRS6Th99mqMo1AeKXTAUBj4GkxKUEgM8iDRulCxGDxQQ6dU51Bkl1i-zo8yYxz0VzwBjIADpbPYbrCGtBjkpjjwIMApDxzJCdGjtDofn8AOYQDDpTE8RTqN4ZSpIEBDAzHGogThWDwmHgeFAQKz1aSyfSnFAfDk4ML8sTuGgmKQTKAAZmUyhErNYtSsGK88hJfIFEiFnGYovFUG1EBohoA7iYaMAABacJViR0QEwkx3ATgAJlVSnVrzZHJQZmlRqlJqgfKoJKdnAArAGdAsYtoyRSqSAYVyeXydAB6Qsnbm84WmjBinicc48MwkyJQWXyxXbXZ9Jt3HSZynAam5st8mEthVN9O97MwsNUCBFkszisx6jx51Qdt7HhdnvkvsDxfTldOl47rP9nM64B6gvaYvNiC6uN86NmmtQOsNpt2h1rjedqDup63qcH+W7KKee4Xg+V5PhAMLfseOhAA)

Comment: Thanks! This was very helpful. In case you are interested in what I needed it for: https://github.com/bergkvist/react-context-toolkit

Answer (score 0):

This is one approach that provides some type-safety, but unfortunately, can still allow a few false positives. Any key is valid with any value, *but* it at least verifies it's a valid key and value.

```js
type Input<Keys, Values> = Array<{ key: Keys; value: Values }>;

type Output<Keys extends string, Values> = { [key in Keys]: Values };

function fromArray<Keys extends string, Values>(
  xs: Input<Keys, Values>
): Output<Keys, Values> {
  const obj = {} as Output<Keys, Values>;
  for (const x of xs) {
    obj[x.key] = x.value;
  }
  return obj;
}

const geometry = fromArray([
  { key: "circle", value: { color: "blue", radius: 3 } },
  { key: "rectangle", value: { color: "red", width: 3, height: 2 } },
  { key: "line", value: { length: 5 } }
]);

// Valid:
geometry.circle.color; // string
geometry.line.length; // number
geometry.rectangle.length; // number, but should not exist
geometry.line.color; // string, but should not exist

// Invalid:
geometry.line.background; // does not exist
geometry.square; // does not exist
```